# JLabel replace error

Tags: java

I wrote a JFrame program. This Frame includes image and a button. When this button is clicked, this image is disappered and JLabel is replaced at this image. I tried it. Although Image is disappeared, JLable cannot replace. How should I do?

Comment: Can u paste the code u tried ?

Comment: Replacing the image/label should work if done correctly. Since it doesn't work it seems you made some error - just which is hard to tell without any code.

Comment: Please send the [mcve] so we can see your code and possibly help.